# Evaluate $\int_0^{\infty} x^2\,e^{-x^2}\,dx$ if it is convergent.

Tags: calculus

evaluate $$\int_0^{\infty} x^2\,e^{-x^2}\,dx$$ if it is convergent. I cannot figure this out for the life of me. Please help!! thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think its ${\sqrt{\pi} \over 4}$.

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate the gaussian integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x^2}$ ? If not then you should start there. If you do then one simple way to evaluate it is to take the derivative with respect to $\lambda$.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is just a routine application of integration by parts. Have you tried that?

Comment: I agree with @NicholasRoberts integrate by parts.

Comment: Polar coordinates can also be used, as done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243066/evaluate-int-0-infty-x2-e-x2dx)

Comment: I would go @Winther's route.